# Переходные и непереходные глаголы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: не размешал раствор для кладки или не размешал раствора для кладки. Я руководствовалась тем, что дополнение при глаголе с отрицанием стоит в родительном падеже, следовательно, не размешал раствора для кладки. Так? Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае лучше использовать В.п.: **не размешал раствор для кладки**.

**Вообще говоря, при отрицании используются оба падежа, при этом надо учитывать влияние различных факторов.** Р.п. используется при необходимости точно выразить своё значение:  разделительно-количественное: не пьет вина, не купил хлеба; при глаголах восприятия: не слышно поезда, при сочетании с отвлеченными предметами: не упускает случая. Также Р.п. чаще используется в книжной речи.

В приведенном примере эти  факторы отсутствуют, речь идет о конкретном  предмете и конкретной ситуации, нет количественно-разделительного значения.